# Google cloud application yaml for angular 7

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

My project directory looks like

```
**demo**
 -->
   **ui**-->
     **dist**-->
       **ui**-->
         *.html
         *.js files


In my app.yaml    

runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true`enter code here`
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: dist/\1/index.html
  upload: dist/(.*)/(.*)
```

Whenever I deploy my app and hit the URL I see getting 404 Failed to load 
 resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () for all the files 
 except index.html.

Any help how to proceed further would be appreciated.

Read stack overflow related questions but no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my setup. You'll notice that there are some subtle nuances with the other answers. These nuances allowed me to deploy my app. And the deployment file is significangtly simpler.

It works with angular 9 and the current version of the app engine (as of 03/2020)

First things first, the `angular.json` file sets the target build directory as follows:

```
"build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/my-awesome-app",
            ...
```

next, you will have to create a `app.yaml` in your `dist` directory. This is your deployment file. Watch out because `dist` is not tracked by git. So you'll either have to fiddle with your `.gitignore` file or copy your `app.yaml` file in `dist` before deploying. (I chose the former).

Your project should then look like this:

```
> my-awesom-app
|  > dist
|  |  > my-awesome-app
|  |  $ app.yaml
```

With `app.yaml` and `dist/my-awesome-app` at the same level.

Next your `app.yaml` file should look like this

```yaml
runtime: nodejs12

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: my-awesome-app/index.html
  upload: my-awesome-app/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: my-awesome-app
```

Answer (score 11):

Here I share the approach I use.

`app.yaml` should looks like :

```
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.+\.js)
  static_files: app/\1
  upload: app/(.+\.js)

- url: /(.+\.css)
  static_files: app/\1
  upload: app/(.+\.css)

- url: /(.+\.png)
  static_files: app/\1
  upload: app/(.+\.png)

- url: /(.+\.jpg)
  static_files: app/\1
  upload: app/(.+\.jpg)

- url: /(.+\.svg)
  static_files: app/\1
  upload: app/(.+\.svg)

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: app/favicon.ico
  upload: app/favicon.ico

- url: /(.+\.json)
  static_files: app/\1
  upload: app/(.+\.json)

- url: /(.+)
  static_files: app/index.html
  upload: app/index.html

- url: /
  static_files: app/index.html
  upload: app/index.html
```

These handlers rules could be optimized. Here, I kept them in a detailed form with each file type.

Directory structure of `deploy` folder should looks like:

```
/deploy
  app.yaml
  /app  =>  generated by ng build
    index.html
    ...bundles..js
    /assets
      ...
```

This default service will be served at `https://YOUR_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com` as usual.

Maybe these links may help your :

- [My answer to an other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56858761/4786620)
- [Deploy Angular 2/4/6 App on Google App Engine](https://medium.com/@asanoop24/deploying-angular-6-app-on-google-app-engine-b6259d4c16c2) by Anoop Sharma

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23441142)

Comment: @JL2210 you're right, really sorry. I updated my answer with the content of my previous answer.  we learn every day. ;-)

Comment: The only answer that actually worked for Angular 7. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've got 404 response, because in cloud shell console I didn't added command for recursive sync `-r`, what made it skipped my project files. 
The command which worked for me was:

```
gsutil -m  rsync -r gs://your-bucket ./your-directory-in-cloudshell
```

`-m` is command for multithread sync, which faster the process.

Notice the relative path to `your-directory-in-cloudshell` while running the command and location where you run it.

Combining this solution with @avi.elkharrat answer made my app works.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To complement @Thierry Falvo answer I want to suggest that if your intention is to upload all the resources such as images, videos, fonts, etc. write a more generic rule like the following.

```yaml
- url: /(.*\.(.+))$
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: app/\1
  upload: app/(.*\.(.+))$
```