# Java - Hosting Angular application on google app engine standard. webapp folder vs. GCS bucket?

Tags: angular, google-app-engine

I have an angular web application that uses App Engine standard JAVA as the backend API.

Whats the best way to host the angular web app under the same project ?

I would like to host the web application under the same google project.

The app works fine when I place the files under src/main/Webapp folder under the Java API project. However, that would require backend APIs to be refreshed every time I need to change the web app.

Alternately, Came across something like this for hosting angular application inside a GCS bucket :
https://medium.com/@asanoop24/deploying-angular-6-app-on-google-app-engine-b6259d4c16c2

Any suggestions on which is the preferred approach for hosting angular web apps on GAE ?

Thanks

Comment: Check out GAE services.  You can have a service for each and update one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach you could consider. I use it for multiple full stack deployments on Google AppEngine Standard, and prefer this (vs GCS) because of GAE features (versioning, split traffic, logs..). But the cost could be higher than a GCS public bucket.

To do that:

**1) deploy a first service for front-end**

Just a simple deployment of your Angular `dist` folder generated by `ng build --prod`.
Choose a simple standard `python` environment to do that.

`app.yaml` should looks like :

```
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.+\.js)
  static_files: app/\1
  upload: app/(.+\.js)

- url: /(.+\.css)
  static_files: app/\1
  upload: app/(.+\.css)

- url: /(.+\.png)
  static_files: app/\1
  upload: app/(.+\.png)

- url: /(.+\.jpg)
  static_files: app/\1
  upload: app/(.+\.jpg)

- url: /(.+\.svg)
  static_files: app/\1
  upload: app/(.+\.svg)

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: app/favicon.ico
  upload: app/favicon.ico

- url: /(.+\.json)
  static_files: app/\1
  upload: app/(.+\.json)

- url: /(.+)
  static_files: app/index.html
  upload: app/index.html

- url: /
  static_files: app/index.html
  upload: app/index.html
```

I'm sure handlers rules could probably be optimized. I'm not an expert in regexp. ;-)

Directory structure of `deploy` folder should looks like:

```
/deploy
  app.yaml
  /app  =>  generated by ng build
    index.html
    ...bundles..js
    /assets
      ...
```

This default service will be served at `https://YOUR_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com` as usual.

**2) Deploy a second service for backend**

Then (and only after 1st front-end deployment), deploy a second service for backend with Java standard environment.

But we precise the name of service, inside `<service>` tag. Here I choose `api`, but any other name should be fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>          
    <instance-class>F4</instance-class>
    ...
    <service>api</service>
    ...
```

This new service will be served at `https://YOUR_SERVICE_NAME-dot-YOUR_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com`, so here `https://api-dot-YOUR_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com`.

Pay attention to manage CORS on backend, to correctly accept request from `https://YOUR_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com`.