# Deploy multi component Angular application to GCP App Engine

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a simple test Angular application on GCP App Engine, however it seems there is a problem with the routing I can't solve.
Here's what I'm doing:

```
ng new gcp
(Would you like to add Angular routing? = yes)
cd gcp
ng generate component test
```

then in `app-routing.module.ts` I'm adding the corresponding route:
`const routes: Routes = [{ path: "test", component: TestComponent }];`

just to make it simpler, I'm changing the `app.component.html` to:

```
<H1>GCP Test</H1>
<a href="/test">Test Component</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

At this point when I execute the application with `"ng serve"` and I open http://localhost:4200 I can see the page served by `app.component.html` and when I click on the "Test Component", I'm redirected to the test component as expected.

in the project folder I created a new `app.yaml` file with the following contents:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
#I also tried playing with the url by adding the commented block below
# - url: /(.+)
#   static_files: dist/gcp/index.html
#   upload: dist/gcp/index.html
- url: /
  static_files: dist/gcp/index.html
  upload: dist/gcp/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: dist/gcp

skip_files:
  - e2e/
  - node_modules/
  - src/
  - coverage
  - ^(.*/)?\..*$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.json$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.md$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.yaml$
  - ^LICENSE
```

at this point I built the project with ng build
after that I deployed the project with `gcloud app deploy --project=<<MyGCPProjectId>>`

When the deployment process returns a success message, I'm trying to open my new project:
`https://<<MyGCPProjectId>>.uc.r.appspot.com`

Again I see the home page of the project, but this time, when I click on the "Test Component" link, I'm redirected to `https://<<MyGCPProjectId>>.uc.r.appspot.com/test` as expected, but this time I see a **404 error "The requested URL /test was not found on this server."**.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please check my previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56858839/4786620, seems to be duplicated question. A lot of other questions/answer of same subject.

Comment: An other advice, you should probably only upload `dist` folder, and add a `.gcloudignore` file to avoid uploading `src`, `node_modules`... to GAE. To do that, copy `dist` folder in a dedicated folder `deploy` for instance, then add your `app.yaml` in this deploy folder.